# History of MathOverflow

Tags: discussion, faq

What is history of this site? When and by whom was it created?

What were the important milestones of this site?

Comment: I've asked about this [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11008935#11008935). Quid encouraged me to post the question if I consider it useful, so I went ahead.

Comment: (Previously part of the question...)
This question was inspired by [History of Math.Stackexchange](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7021/history-of-math-stackexchange). There is also a post [What’s the story behind mathoverflow?](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/186/whats-the-story-behind-mathoverflow-/) on tea.

Comment: Wayback Machine: [What’s the story behind mathoverflow?](https://web.archive.org/web/20160410152045/http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/186/whats-the-story-behind-mathoverflow-/)

Comment: I have a precise "historical" question. Were there less restrictions at the beginning (2009, maybe 2010) to upvote posts? Indeed there's a profusion at these early times of highly upvoted answers. Or does it only result from a change of behavior among the MO users?

Answer (score 31):

## History of MathOverflow

## Milestones

**September 28, 2009:** [MathOverflow goes online](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1/ignore-this-question)

**October 10, 2009:** [MathOverflow is announced](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/10/14/math-overflow/) at the Secret Blogging Seminar

**December 2009** [Greg Kuperberg](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1450/greg-kuperberg) became the first user to reach [10k reputation](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/mathoverflow/2009-12-20?sort=totalreputation)

**June 2010:** featured in the [AMS Notices](http://www.ams.org/notices/201006/index.html).

**October 2010:** [10000 users](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/706/user-10000/) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20151031231532/http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/706/user-10000/))

**June 2012:** [100000th post](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/1389/another-milestone/) (including the deleted ones) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20161024013324/http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1389/another-milestone/))

**June 24, 2013:** MathOverflow [joined SE network](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/1416/6/mathoverflow-20/) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20161024073543/http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1416/6/mathoverflow-20/))

**September 17, 2014:** [Joel David Hamkins](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1946/joel-david-hamkins) becomes the first user to reach 100k reputation.

**February 11, 2019:** [100000 questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2019/2/11)

**November 2022:** [User with 200,000 reputation](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5516/we-have-our-first-user-with-more-than-200k-reputation)

## Moderators

**September 2009 - October 2009:** [Anton Geraschenko](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1/anton-geraschenko), [David Zureick-Brown](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2/david-zureick-brown), [Daniel Erman](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4/daniel-erman) and [Scott Morrison](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3/scott-morrison)

**October 2009 - June 2010:** [Anton Geraschenko](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1/anton-geraschenko), [Ben Webster](https://mathoverflow.net/users/66/ben-webster), [David Zureick-Brown](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2/david-zureick-brown), [Daniel Erman](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4/daniel-erman) and [Scott Morrison](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3/scott-morrison)

**June 2010 - October 2013:** [Anton Geraschenko](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1/anton-geraschenko), [Ben Webster](https://mathoverflow.net/users/66/ben-webster), [David Zureick-Brown](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2/david-zureick-brown),
[François G. Dorais](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2000/francois-g-dorais),
[S. Carnahan](https://mathoverflow.net/users/121/s-carnahan) and [Scott Morrison](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3/scott-morrison)

**October 2013 - April 2021:** [Ben Webster](https://mathoverflow.net/users/66/ben-webster), [David Zureick-Brown](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2/david-zureick-brown),
[François G. Dorais](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2000/francois-g-dorais),
[S. Carnahan](https://mathoverflow.net/users/121/s-carnahan), [Scott Morrison](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3/scott-morrison), [Mariano Suárez-Alvarez](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1409/mariano-suarez-alvarez) and [Todd Trimble](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2926/todd-trimble)

**April 2021 - January 2022:** [Ben Webster](https://mathoverflow.net/users/66/ben-webster), [David Zureick-Brown](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2/david-zureick-brown),
[François G. Dorais](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2000/francois-g-dorais),
[S. Carnahan](https://mathoverflow.net/users/121/s-carnahan), [Todd Trimble](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2926/todd-trimble), [Stefan Kohl](https://mathoverflow.net/users/28104/stefan-kohl), [Asaf Karagila](https://mathoverflow.net/users/7206/asaf-karagila) and [Tim Campion](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2362/tim-campion).

**January 2022 - October 2022:** [Ben Webster](https://mathoverflow.net/users/66/ben-webster), [David Zureick-Brown](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2/david-zureick-brown),
[S. Carnahan](https://mathoverflow.net/users/121/s-carnahan), [Todd Trimble](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2926/todd-trimble), [Stefan Kohl](https://mathoverflow.net/users/28104/stefan-kohl), [Asaf Karagila](https://mathoverflow.net/users/7206/asaf-karagila) and [Tim Campion](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2362/tim-campion).

**October 2022 - Present:** [Ben Webster](https://mathoverflow.net/users/66/ben-webster),
[S. Carnahan](https://mathoverflow.net/users/121/s-carnahan), [Todd Trimble](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2926/todd-trimble), [Stefan Kohl](https://mathoverflow.net/users/28104/stefan-kohl), [Asaf Karagila](https://mathoverflow.net/users/7206/asaf-karagila), [Tim Campion](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2362/tim-campion), and [David Roberts](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4177/david-roberts).

Comment: That SBS comment thread brings back some happy highways where I went...

Comment: It might be good to list birthday statistics, as well as those events that were considered major policy changes, e.g. when the content was being steered away from soft questions and those that are considered by some to be not research level questions.

Comment: I'd also like to know more about the statistics.  Am I right in my sense that MathOverflow has seen a significant drop in usage?

Comment: @JessRiedel it depends what you have in mind precisely; see for example http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/853 for some data compiled by François G. Dorais and me. I would say there is no somewhat recent significant drop, but in the long run the overall activity declined a bit (why and if or in what sense this is/could be a problem is a bit too broad for this comment).

Comment: I have added the moderators from the beginning of MO according to information mentioned [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11783078#11783078). Although I am not sure when Daniel Erman stopped being moderator. And perhaps before the migration Anton Geraschenko should be listed as an administrator, not a moderator. (I hope some old-timers will correct this information, if needed.)

Comment: I have also added the things that were mentioned [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/revisions/7021/2).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: on June 24, 2013: MathOverflow joined **SE2** network.

Comment: I think Mariano lost his diamond quite some time prior to April 2021. But I can't recall when exactly right now.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You probably mean this: [Were there some recent changes to the moderators' team?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3917) Based on what [Anton Geraschenko said in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57594086#57594086), it seems that nothing new is known about the situation.

Comment: Thank you to François for his time as a moderator!

Comment: I'd find practical to separate the list real events (first blah blah) to the (arbitrary) list of decimal records (10000000th occurrence of the letter E in a post, etc).

Comment: Should we add "January 2022 -- viewing reputation becomes opt-in"? It seems an important change in how the site presents itself.

Comment: Mods need updating....

Comment: @DavidRoberts Feel free to go ahead - after all the answer is [community wiki](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/community-wiki/info).

Answer (score 20):

On January 30, 2014, [Joel David Hamkins](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1946/joel-david-hamkins) posted his [1000th answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62401/logic-in-mathematics-and-philosophy/156211#156211) on MathOverflow. Congratulations!

[image: User Page]

Comment: Wow! Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks, François, you are very kind to mention it. It's surely been a lot of fun! And I've learned a lot.

Comment: Not to put you under undue pressure @JoelDavidHamkins but we expect  the 100k points celebration somewhat soonish now. :-) Congratulations!

Comment: @quid, I shall look forward to that party. (But it is not actually in my control!)

Comment: Well, one upvote to each of those answers = 10k rep :-) (I'm not saying to do it, the mods have superpowers and can tell...)

Comment: And now, Igor Rivin just reached his 999th answer!

Comment: @Gil: Here is Igor's 1000th: http://mathoverflow.net/a/167358

Answer (score 16):

On September 17th, 2014, [Joel David Hamkins](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1946/joel-david-hamkins) became the first user on MathOverflow with more than 100000 points.  Congratulations!

[image: User profile]

(It seems the "deciding" vote was cast on https://mathoverflow.net/a/172711/.)

Comment: Maybe also the link to this weeks [reputation league](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/251/week/mathoverflow/2014-09-14?sort=totalreputation) can be added. (Although it will probably need until tomorrow to update.)

Comment: Thanks, quid, how kind of you to notice it. It's surely been a lot of fun!

Comment: Congratulations, Joel.

Comment: My pleasure, @JoelDavidHamkins!

Comment: Thanks for adding the image @Todd

Comment: JDH writes some personal reflections here: http://jdh.hamkins.org/mathoverflow-the-eternal-fountain-of-mathematics-reflections-on-a-hundred-kiloreps/

Answer (score 11):

The historical first MO golden badge was awarded to Charles Siegel for [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/5052/1532).

[image]

**Update:** Here is a historical [snapshot](http://gilkalai.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/mo8.jpg) (click for a better resolution) of top participators shortly after Charles earned his golden medal. This was shortly after Greg's sprint to (questionless) 10K reputations record. Note also that Andrew ranked 7th at the time has only bronze badges, and that Reid Barton has precisely 6666 points.

Comment: If you want to collect such stories, maybe add the heroic but in the end hopeles fight of Andrew Stacey against the badeges http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/190/how-do-i-sell-a-badge/ and http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1364/a-sad-day-/

Comment: Dear Quid, yes this is indeed a famous story that will be told from fathers to sons. I am afraid I was involved with Andrew's silver and gold best badges. The badge system is a wonderful way for multi-dimensional appreciation systems where every user can even define his own peculiar aims.

Comment: Tom Leinster recently got the first gold badge on meta for http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1042/antons-departure-as-moderator

Comment: BTW since MO joined SE you can also view top users at some moment in the past using *reputation leagues*. For example, here are [top users from Dec 2009](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/251/month/mathoverflow/2009-12-01?sort=totalreputation). Comparing with the snapshot you posted, it seems to be around the same time. (Although this shows the reputation from Dec 2009, but badges are shown from the present.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Wow, I had not realized that Greg had gained 7000 points in one month.

Comment: @S.Carnahan Well, there might have been some mix-up when moving from old MO to the SE network, which would make date from reputation leagues unreliable. But since the numbers there seem to be rather similar to the numbers in the screenshot, I'd guess that they are probably correct.

Answer (score 7):

[Jim Belk](https://mathoverflow.net/users/6514/jim-belk) performing [perfectly centered breaks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156263/perfectly-centered-break-of-a-perfectly-aligned-pool-ball-rack) at the request of [user2376055](https://mathoverflow.net/users/46254/user2376055) drew a huge crowd of spectators.

Now, **on February 11, 2014** the count reached 100,000, and this in only slightly over 10 days, making this not only the currently most viewed question on MO, but **the first question to reach 100,000 views** in MO's history.

Fun side-aspect: the success of the question was so massive that some even [expressed doubt this is happening for real.](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1478/viewed-67597-times)

In the unlikely event you have not yet seen it, here it is once again, the perfectly centered break according to Jim Belk.

[image: Perfectly center break as animated gif]

Comment: Is there a way to sort questions by number of views?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar no, but yes. By which I mean there is no way via tabs and the standard userinterface, but one can get such lists via the data explorer. See for example  http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/166766/most-views for a list of all questions sorted by views (with at least 5000 views). If one just cares about those with relatively many one could also look for those with famous question badge, that is +10k.

Comment: GeraldEdgar: This seems also related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/most-upvoted-and-viewed-questions The link mentioned there is: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/greatest-hits I am not sure about exact algorithm, but this page seems to combine somehow score and number of views.

Comment: As a side-note, [a question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733754/visually-stunning-math-concepts-which-are-easy-to-explain) on math.SE recently (to date) got 126380 views in 11 days. This says maybe this phenomenon isn't going to be as surprising in the near future :) Hopefully it sparks some STEM careers.