# Viewed 67597 Times

Tags: support

Something strange here: [Perfectly centered break of a perfectly aligned pool ball rack](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156263/)

---

[image: viewed]

Comment: Please reserve the [tag:bug] tag for software bugs in the site. This page was probably shared on a social media site.

Comment: Are you asking where all those views come from? I don't see anything strange here.

Comment: @MadScientist: What I found surprising is that many views in six days. In one week this has become one of our most popular question/answers, surpassing 40,000 others. But quid's analysis indicates there is nothing amiss here. I must say it shows MO to a good light. Kudos to Jim Belk!

Comment: Meanwhile it is the question with most views ever on MO, already *very* close to 100k.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Searching for 'mathoverflow 156263', the number is the questions number, I find various links to the question. It seems this question just somehow became really popular way beyond the usual audience, yet there is nothing wrong about this; it already had really many views earlier. To wit, OP of q got the famous question badge already on February 3rd, so already then it had 10k+ views.

I only protected the question, since it attracted two non-answers by new users. Other than that I think there is nothing particular to be done about this (perhaps even protecting was not necessary). It might be (yet) another instance to show that this asssociation voting is not so good, but then at least in this case OP of answer made a lot of effort and provided good information so in some sense it is really a great answer.

More playfully, one could say  MathOverflow has now its analogue of the [Batman equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real).

Comment: This post was shared on reddit (not by me, although I enjoy sharing mathoverflow posts on reddit). It was very popular there.

Comment: @BrianRushton yeah, my first thought was you were to "blame." :-) But I checked if somebody got some of the promotion badges, but apparently it was shared without tracing or by a nonuser (which made me abandon the idea it was you).