# A tribute to the owners of the set-theory golden tag

Tags: discussion

In this slightly unusual and relaxed post, 
I would like to express my admiration for
our all-time top rep user [Joel David Hamkins](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1946/joel-david-hamkins),
in the spirit of the [jon-skeet-facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) post
from the sibling stackoverflow site, and more generally to the set-theoretic community here on mathoverflow.

Please don't take it too seriously.

The reputation of Joel David Hamkins is $\omega+136{,}366$. 
A bug in the mathoverflow software prevents the display of the $\omega$.

Q: Can Joel David Hamkins ask a question that even Joel David Hamkins can't answer?
A: Yes. And he can answer it, too.

One day Joel David Hamkins gave a cryptic answer.
The Cray Institute offers \$1000000 for the first one to decipher it.

There is a special gold badge for Joel David Hamkins.
It is called set theory.

One day twenty Fields medalists decided to ask on mathoverflow 
if the Riemann hypothesis is true.
Unfortunately, they forgot to use the `set-theory` tag,
and the question remains unsolved to this day.

There is a technique in set theory called forcing.
There is a technique on mathoverflow called Hamkins.

The dining philosophers wait while Joel David Hamkins eats.

Joel David Hamkins can recite $\pi$. Backwards.

Joel David Hamkins is in the top 0,00% overall.

Joel David Hamkins's computer did not succeed in taking a snapshot
of Joel David Hamkins's profile at 100000 rep. It was not fast enough.

When Joel David Hamkins makes a choice, the Axiom of Choice agrees.

Joel David Hamkins knows if the infinite is even or odd.

Comment: If it doesn't fit, don't force it; ask Joel instead. In what universe could this possibly hold? All of them. Gerhard "Could Go On All Day" Paseman, 2017.03.30.

Comment: There are a couple of places to celebrate achievements on MO or by MO users.  For example, see http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/753/history-of-mathoverflow/1454#1454 or http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/753/history-of-mathoverflow/1902#1902 or http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/617/best-of-mathoverflow/ .   And by the way there are two users with the gold badge for set theory.

Comment: @Lucia Indeed let me pay my due respect to Andreas Blass right here. On the other hand the posts you mention have a slightly more serious tone so I thought it was more appropriate to make a separate post.

Comment: I just found this post---hilarious! Thanks for the tribute, @coudy.  In the spirit of the question, and with enormous risk of annoying people, let me add a few more: when JDH plays infinite chess against himself, he wins on both sides!  JDH's large cardinals can prove their own consistency! JDH is not of this universe---he lives in all set-theoretic universes. JDH doesn't need axoms to prove his theorems---he proves everything from the empty theory. JDH's supertask machines complete infinitely many steps of computation in a finite amount of time! All his large cardinals are indestructible!

Comment: The dining philosophers badge and reciting $\pi$ backwards badge were awarded to Jon Skeet first. Sorry, Joel David Hamkins.

Comment: I made some edits.  I wish I had a sufficiently good sense of humour to know whether "Cray Institute" is intentional or a typo.  :-)

Comment: The number of MO points of @JoelDavidHamkins as a function of time is bounded by a computable function -- in *some* model of Peano Arithmetic.