# Diamond moderator symbols and old posts

Tags: feature-request, bug, user-accounts, moderators

This question, or rather, (vague) feature-request is not specific to MO; however I leave it to more experienced (and with better skill in writing English) users to possibly ask it elsewhere.

> Explanatory example: Reading the comments to [this meta question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/2068/14094), one can read a 2014 exchange of comments between "Stefan Kohl ◊ Mod" and "François G Dorais". But paradoxically, in 2014, François G Dorais was a moderator and Stefan Kohl wasn't.

This bug can make the reading of old conversations clumsy. In this case, since I've been active on MO for 10 years, I'm aware of the various roles. But on another site, or if I were a recent user, this conversation would have sounded confusing.

Here the contents of the exchange is not that important, but typically a message by a moderator can have some "official"/"authoritative" flavor and not just a personal opinion, and hence be interpreted differently (whence the usefulness of displaying the moderator diamond... when accurate).

The issue can also occur for questions/answers, with the additional difficulty that the date is then not unique (a post can be edited several years later...).

So I believe the output should reflect this.

The most obvious (partial) solution would be that the diamond signs for comments take into account the date, and for posts/answers, the first date of posting.

Comment: An old related feature request on Meta SE: [Allow ex-moderators to opt-in to having a mark on their profile indicating they were a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181668). It was marked [status-completed] presumably because the [Sheriff gold badge](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/175/sheriff) seemed to serve the required purpose.

Comment: Another related post on Meta SE: [Keep track of historical user (moderator) status and make available in profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263729).

Comment: François G. Dorais is not a moderator anymore?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi See here: [History of MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/753#754). The edit removing his name from the list was done by François G. Dorais himself - so I would consider that as a reliable enough confirmation. https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/754/revisions https://meta.mathoverflow.net/revisions/754/18 (And he is also not listed among the moderators - but sometimes a mod can be removed from that list also as a precaution which can be later reversed, as [discussed in another post](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3917#3919) on this meta.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: thank you, I missed this