# "A year in moderation" post on MathOverflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderation, statistics

You might have noticed than many Stack Exchange sites have some statistics about both community moderation and moderators' activity posted on meta under the title "2018: a year in moderation". Here is a post [on Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29577/2018-a-year-in-moderation) and you can find similar posts [on many other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=2018%3A+a+year+in+moderation+is%3Aq). As far as I can tell, this was done on almost all per-site metas, the main exception seem to be the sites that are [less than one year old](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7469230#7469230). The fact that there are only a few sites where such post is missing was mentioned also in this post on Meta Stack Exchange: [No “2018: A year in moderation” here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321323)

In my opinion knowing these statistics is interesting. It is a way to see how much is the community involved in site moderation and maintenance. Also the level of the workload for moderators was [discussed relatively recently](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3866/should-we-have-new-moderator-elections), knowing these statistics might also be interesting in that context.

Should we ask for similar post also on MathOverflow Meta? Or are there some reasons specific to this site why these statistics should not be made public?

EDIT: Link to a conversation in chat related to extending this request to the following years: ["Year in moderation" posts on MathOverflow](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9369/conversation/year-in-moderation-posts-on-mathoverflow). It contains links to various comments by MO users and mods related to this topic.

Comment: The post with moderation statistics is now posted here: [2018: a year in moderation](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4062).

Comment: For the 2018 version, I was not automatically welcoming (see my comment there); that may  contribute to a delayed response.  It might be useful to have suggestions for types of mod stats in this thread, and see what can be provided.  Of interest to me are things that aren't in SQL, such as time spent dealing with misbehaving sock puppets, and other aspects of which no details should be mentioned, but aggregates might help the community at large.  Gerhard "Has Only Well-Behaved Sock Puppets" Paseman, 2020.01.07.

Answer (score 4):

Request renewed for the 2019 stats (and happy new 2020 to everyone!). I am surprised that this post was not created automatically on MO like on the other sites.

EDIT: and tagging this feature-request, otherwise no one at SE will see this (and I am not even sure it is sufficient, but I don't know what else I can do apart from pinging them in an unrelated post).

Comment: Regarding your recent edit, I have [mentioned this to Shog9](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4062/2018-a-year-in-moderation?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment21417_4062).

Comment: I will add this concerning the paragraph [added in the edit](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/revisions/4415/3): [How to contact a MathOverflow user?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3634) (The linked posts is about possible wasys to contacting a specific user.)

Comment: Here you go: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4422/2019-a-year-in-moderation (cc @MartinSleziak)

Comment: How did that "happy new 2020" work out for everyone? (Yes, I know, hindsight is 20-20....)