# Three-vote close?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

MO users might be interested in this StackExchange experiment:
[Testing three-vote close and reopen on 13 network sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364007/228808).
There has been considerable discussion around close-votes in MO Meta over the years. My own opinion is that a move from $5$ to $3$ votes would not be
beneficial for MO.

It might be useful to become prepared to answer a
possible future request from StackExchange on this issue.

Comment: Somehow it seems to me that the move from 5 to 3 votes would be more beneficial for _reopening_ than for _closing_. For _closing_ it might help reduce the workload of filtering out homework questions, but there might be a lot of babies thrown out with that bathwater.

Comment: It would be great if we had quantitative data about this. How many questions have we had recently that stopped at 3 or 4 close (or reopen) votes? Is there a list, so that we can see for ourselves if they are baby or bathwater?

Comment: Certain controversial questions have produced close/reopen wars in the past. The new rule would speed these up by a factor of 5/3. That's probably not a good thing.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Those close/reopen wars are rare, and generally get by resolved by moderator intervention in any case.  I think this change should be judged on its effect in the more common cases, not the rare ones!

Comment: If close/reopen wars are a concern, we could suggest SE to implement an increasing threshold: 3 votes to close/reopen the first time, 5 the second time, 7 the third, ...

Comment: I guess a good strategy about close/reopen question cannot be seriously discussed without seriously studying the history of such questions.

Comment: Making it easier to close a question makes it harder for the user posting the question to improve it before it gets closed.

Comment: I think it is not even easy to predict whether reducing the number of votes required to close a question would actually lead to questions being closed faster. -- There may also be an opposite effect that makes one more reluctant to vote to close if one's vote has a higher weight. In any case, as long as there is no bigger problem with the current setup, I'd be very careful with such change which may have various hard-to-predict consequences.

Comment: At the present, as far as I know, there is no plan to implement this change for sites that not explicitely ask for it. All the sites in the experiment (and some others) have asked for it!

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, [re](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5028/three-vote-close#comment25784_5028), surely the proper number of votes the third time is 8, and then 13 the fourth time?

Comment: Just a passer by, but seeing the year in moderation stats [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4839/2020-a-year-in-moderation) it looks like most of the closing is done by mods. If they have a desire to lighten that workload moving to 3 vote closures could be beneficial.

Comment: @Luuklag Could you clarify what you mean by "most of the closing is done by mods"? The post you linked says: Questions closed - 138 Moderators, 3258 Community. (For reopened questions, the numbers shown there are 10 and 20.)

Comment: Ouch @MartinSleziak I mixed up the columns in my head.